# Visualising Categorical Data across a Time Frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

still fairly new to R and have stepped away for a while, so please bear with me.
I have a set of data which describes the degree of mobility (categorical data) after an operation across 3 days.  I have been looking for a way to demonstrate the flow across those 3 days.

I've tried using `geom_jitter` with x and y being Day 1 and 2, and `aes(colour)` being Day 3 but this doesn't really convey what I want to show.  I've done some reading around Sankey Diagram and Parallel Coordinates but have not got the understanding to quite fit the samples posed by others to fit my data.

This is what I've tried:

```
test %>% filter(!is.na(Mob_D1.factor) & !is.na(Mob_D2.factor) & !is.na(Mob_D3.factor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Mob_D1.factor, y = Mob_D2.factor, colour = Mob_D3.factor)) + 
  geom_jitter(size = 5, alpha = 0.25, height = 0.25, width = 0.2) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2", name = "Mobilisation on Day 3") +
  xlab("Mobilisation on Day 1") +
  ylab("Mobilisation on Day 2") + theme_minimal()
```

As I said, not quite what I want.

This is a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(Mob_D1.factor = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("None", 
"Bed", "Stand", "Assisted Walk"), class = "factor"), Mob_D2.factor = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("None", "Bed", "Stand", "Assisted Walk"), class = "factor"), 
    Mob_D3.factor = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("None", 
    "Bed", "Stand", "Assisted Walk"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to reply.  Any extended explanation would be appreciated as I am still learning.

Larry

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what the expected result should be, but could a barplot be helpful?

**Edit**

I now think I understand what you need and I found the package `ggalluvial` that can help you with this.

Hope this helps.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

# Some data wrangling first. Add row_number to give a unique ID for each patient
d <- df %>% mutate(Patient = row_number()) %>% 
   # transform it to longer format
   pivot_longer(col=(-Patient), values_to = "Stage", names_to = "Day")

# Make the plot
ggplot(d,
   aes(x = Day, stratum = Stage, alluvium = Patient,
               fill = Stage, label = Stage)) +
      scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
      geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback",
                color = "darkgray") +
      geom_stratum()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: nice visualisation for this problem. Have you ever considered using the `reprex` package? If you're using RStudio, it fully integrates with it, and includes the image output, super convenient. And you'll also never forget to load the required packages again

Comment: I was aware of the `reprex` package, but didn't use it so far. Very nice indeed. Thanks for pointing it out @Tjebo

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.  I was looking for a way to show the transition of each observation over the 3 days to see roughly what proportion goes from, e.g. bed to stand to walk and what proportion regresses back to bed, hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think this is what I want to do, having done a bit of reading around the `alluvial` package

```
test <- test %>%
  mutate(number = 1)
  
test2 <- aggregate(number ~ Mob_D1.factor + Mob_D2.factor + Mob_D3.factor, data = test, sum)

alluvial(test2[, 1:3], freq = test2$number)
```